# Has Candyland always had a lose-a-turn square?

Tags: candy-land

I just played a brand new version of Candyland and noticed several squares that cause a player to lose a turn if they land on them. The squares are decorated with licorice to associate them with the nefarious [Lord Licorice, who was added as a character in the 1980s](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/4507/675).

Has Candyland always had lose-a-turn spaces, and if so, how were they decorated in the pre Lord Licorice era?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[No.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Candy_Land#Gameplay)  The version I played didn't have those; it had three spaces with "sticky" dots (largish, round, and black).

> Before the 2004 version, there were three colored spaces marked with a dot. A player who lands on such a space is stuck (all cards are ignored) until a card is drawn of the same color as the square. In the 2004 version, dot spaces were replaced with licorice spaces that prompt the player landing on it to simply lose his or her next turn. If you land on a piece of gum, you go back to the start.